# Android: Backspace won't delete newline character set with setText

Tags: android

I'm appending a new line character to the end of the EditText using

```
mEditText.append("\n");
```

inside the `afterTextChanged()` method of the EditText. Now I can't backspace the new line or anything that comes before it. Any ideas?

Comment: `I can't backspace the new line` means exactly what in code?

Comment: Are you creating a circular loop? textchange -> append -> trigger text change -> append? Perhaps add a log inside your afterTextChanged to see when it is being called.

Comment: @roostertech that was the problem. thanks! if you write an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you creating a circular loop? textchange -> append -> trigger text change -> append? Perhaps add a log inside your afterTextChanged to see when it is being called.

:)